# Does a rotating disk with uniformly distributed charges have energy radiation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, charge

**Problem:**

A disk of radius 10 cm is injected with an amount of charge of 3×10^−12 C, uniformly distributed along the edge of the disk. The disk rotates with an angular velocity of 10 rad/s. Find the rate at which energy is radiated by the system.

**My Thoughts:**

Since the charges are uniformly distributed on the edge of the disk, won't that make it be a rotating ring of charges? And if so, I remember reading something saying that a rotating ring of charges does not radiate.

However, I feel like I might be going about this the wrong way, if so I would like if someone directed me along the right route to solve this problem, perhaps with some thoughts or formulas.

Thank you!

Comment: Uniform circular motion of the charges mean all of them feel acceleration and accelerated charges radiate

Comment: A rotating ring of charges does radiate. Indeed this is one of the limiting factors for building very high power circular electron colliders like LEP. The synchotron radiation consumes a significant part of the power needed to run the accelerator.

Comment: A rotating ring of $N$ separated point charges radiates, but the radiation decreases as $N\rightarrow\infty$. This is a problem in Jackson’s EM textbook. In the limit of a continuously charged ring, there is no radiation, because no multipole moment is changing.